# How do I solve this differentiation problem?

Tags: calculus

[image: The problem]
[image: What I’ve tried so far]

I know that the part where I wrote 9y^2 + 7 = 1 was kinda wrong, I am not sure I can do that. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ y = 3x^3+7x $ then taking the differential with respect to $x$ we have $ y_x' = 9x^2+7 $. 
Now let us take the differential with respect to $y$ so we have $ 1 = 9x^2x_y'+7x_y' $ which is $ x_y' = \frac{1}{9x^2+7} $ so the general expression for differentials of inverse functions is:
$$ x_y' = \frac{1}{y_x'} $$

Answer (score 0):

What do you know about the graph of $f$ compared with the graph of $g$?